# How to do something while sprite being touched (Android AndEngine)?

Tags: android, touch, andengine, sprite

I want to play sound with a some periodicity while I hold touch on sprite. I tried to use while with flag, but recieved unending cycle.

```
scene.setOnAreaTouchListener(new IOnAreaTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, ITouchArea pTouchArea, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
            ifHold = true;
            if(pTouchArea.equals(kick1Sprite)){
                while(ifHold){
                    try {
                        kickSound.play();
                        Thread.sleep(soundLoopTimeMilliseconds);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
            ifHold = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sound to be played when it is touch down then make it play and stop it when you making action up as follows:

```
 if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
kickSound.play();
}
 if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
kickSound.stop();
}
```